# shifting in output of NN results (matlab)

Tags: matlab

I hope somebody will clarify my misunderstanding of the situation, described further… I just for educational purposes wrote a very simple code…

```
x = getX();
y = getY();
net = feedforwardnet([50,25]);
net.trainParam.epochs = 500;
net.trainParam.showWindow = false;
n1 rain(net,x,y,'showResources','no','useParallel','yes','useGPU','yes');
r = n1(x);
```

Then I check how it works I used a data set, which looks like:

```
DataSet4Check:
  X     Y
1 2 3   1
2 3 4   2
3 4 5   3
4 5 6   4
etc.
```

I think absolute values of numbers don't play main role here, the dataset above is given just for illustrate a pattern within the set... And I got a very transparent result:

```
CheckResult:
R   Y
1   1
2   2
3   3
etc.
```

But than I slightly changed the dataset:

```
Second DataSet:
X2      Y2
1 2 3   -1
2 3 4   0
3 4 5   1
4 5 6   2
etc.
```

And I got an absolutely unexpected result

```
Scond Result
R2   Y2
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    3
```

The NN output lags on one step from TargetData and the first couple of X2 and Y2 just fallen out from the NN result... Can anybody explane - what exactly wrong ijn my example?

Thanks in edvance!

Comment: Can you please expand a little bit, I tried to replicate your problem, but I couldn't. How big is the training dataset? why the second result Y2 starts at 0 and not at -1?

Comment: Thanks for you answer!
Well, the datasets are large enough. It may have from 3 to 18 thousands examples.
Values of figures in my question are just for simplicity. Real figures much more differ. 
Different sets contain different data ranges, for example: from 100 to 5000 in the first; from -1.5 to 1.5 in the second; from 100.9 to 500.1 in the third. Figures are just dataflow from different types of sensors. 
My main aim is to get WHOLE set on a graph. Thanks one more time!

Comment: Figures? graph? I don't follow. So as I understand, when you train with the first dataset (X,Y), and then test it with same input(X), it works ok (R=Y), but when you retrain with a different dataset (X2,Y2), and test with that input (X2), then the output is shifted (R2=/=Y2). Is my understanding ok? How big is the dataset 2?

Comment: thank you for bothering! the task solved.

Answer (score 0):

The task is solved. I just cheated the NN )))